# Model object<Model.class> is not registered with a Database. Did you forget an annotation?

Tags: android, dbflow

DBFlow Version:4.2.4

Bug or Feature Request:Bug

Description:Have upgraded the library from `4.0.0-beta1` to `4.2.4`.Included the library in my gradle file as follows:-

`dbFlow                   : "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:4.2.4",
dbFlowProcessor          : "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:4.2.4",
dbFlowCore               : "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:4.2.4"`

My application class is as follows;-

`FlowManager.init(FlowConfig.builder(this)
                .addDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig.builder(TestDatabase.class)
                        .databaseName("test_database")
                        .build())
                .build());`

Our TestDatabase.class is as follows:-

`@Database(version = TestDatabase.VERSION)
public class TestDatabase {
    public static final int VERSION = 11;
}`

Following is the stacktrace:-

`Caused by: com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.InvalidDBConfiguration: Model object: com.xxxx.TestMember is not registered with a Database. Did you forget an annotation?
                                                                       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.FlowManager.getDatabaseForTable(FlowManager.java:141)
                                                                       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.FlowManager.getModelAdapterOrNull(FlowManager.java:469)
                                                                       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.FlowManager.getTableName(FlowManager.java:79)
                                                                       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.From.getTableAlias(From.java:43)
                                                                       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.From.getQuery(From.java:211)
                                                                       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.Where.getQuery(Where.java:189)
                                                                       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.BaseModelQueriable.querySingle(BaseModelQueriable.java:67)
                                                                       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.Where.querySingle(Where.java:249)`

TestMember.class is as follows:-

```
@Table(database = TestDatabase.class, cachingEnabled = true)
public class TestMemberextends BaseModel implements Serializable {

    @Column
    public String name;

    @Column
    public String username;

    @Column
    public String phone;

    @PrimaryKey
    public String id;

    @Column
    public String pictureUrl;

    @Column
    public String thumb;

    @Column
    public String status;

    @Column
    public String members;

    @Column
    public String membersUsernames;

    @Column
    public String admin;

    @Column
    public String adminUsername;

    @Column
    public String presence;

    @Column
    public boolean isBlocked;

    @Column
    public boolean isMuted;

    @Column(defaultValue = "0")
    public int placeholder;

    public TestMember() {
    }

    public TestMember(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        TestMember testMember= (TestMember) obj;
        return this.id.equals(TestMember.id);
    }

}
```

Help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation which was handled by the new version of dbFlow was breaking, renaming classes `TestMember.class` and `TestDatabase.class` worked for me.